# Twitter OAuth update_profile_image

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I try to update my profile image and use this code:

```
$connection->post('account/update_profile_image', array('image' => "/images/logo.png"));
```

But it didn't work. I don't know why. How can I update my profile image using the Twitter OAuth Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TwitterOAuth does not currently support image uploads. If you would like to upload images [tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth) is a good library that supports files.

Comment: This library don't have authorization. But I need user authorization.

Comment: tmhOAuth does do authorization.